# Scikit Learn: How can I set the SVM Output range in regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, regression

I have some input data in the range `[-1 , 1]` and output data in the range `[ 0, 1]`. When I use the SMV regression to predict the output
    I have that the  predicted output values are between-1 and 1. What am I
    missing? The code is:

```
    svr=svm.SVR(C=0.1, gamma=0.01,kernel='rbf') 
    y_rbf =svr.fit(TrainingIn,TrainingOut) 
    y_hat=svr.predict(TestIn)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a sample entry of your training data?

Answer (score 1):

Am keeping this answer only for future reference (it does not directly answer PSan's question).

It's important to note that (perhaps contrary to its name) `sklearn.svm.SVR` can be used as both a predictor and a classifier. If fed labeled data, [`predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn.svm.SVR.predict) will output *{-1, +1}*.

Comment: Please,could  you explain better? Sorry, I am not sure I understand well your reply

Comment: This answer is completely wrong, it confuses SVM [support vector machine] with SVR [support vector regression].

Comment: Check the question. He's running SVR.

Comment: Yes, he is, and your answer has nothing to do with SVR, in particular "You are performing here a one-class fitting" - no, he is not, he is performing regression

Comment: I am less and less sure we are even talking about the same thing. Perhaps we can see on which specific point we disagree. The question is **not** about SVR/SVM in general, but about the specific ``SVR`` class in the ``svm`` module.  The documentation clearly states, that ``sklearn.svm.SVR``,  - it's SV**R** name notwithstanding - serves as both a regressor and a classifer. Given a labeled input for train, it will "predict" +1 / -1; it is performing a "classify predict". Feel free to state the exact point with which you disagree.

Comment: @PSan Sorry, I missed your question. My understanding from your question is that you're inadvertently running a classification algorithm. Please see also the discussion with lejlot.

Comment: mmm... if I understand well, if  it were classification, I should have the output equal to 1 or -1 instead I have continuous values between -1 and 1 so it is working as regression. I was just  wondering if  I could  set in someway the output range. I haven' t the data now so I can't show them

Comment: Got you. In this case, I misread/misunderstood your question. I suggest you follow Matt's advice and try to share the data somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Given the information here, it's impossible to reconstruct your problem. I'm pretty sure though, that it has to do with the preprocessing/scaling of your data. An example snippet to get `SVR` running might look like this (feel free to adapt it to your needs):

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# replace this parth with your data, e.g. TrainingIn/TrainingOut
boston = load_boston()
X, y = boston.data, boston.target

X1, X2, y1, y2 = train_test_split(X, y)
svr = SVR(C=80)
scaler = StandardScaler()
svr.fit(scaler.fit_transform(X1), y1)
y_pred = svr.predict(scaler.transform(X2))

print mean_squared_error(y2, y_pred)
```

Comment: I scaled in this way:   scalerI = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
scalerI.fit(TrainingIn_ps)
TrainingIn = scalerI.transform(TrainingIn_ps)    
TestIn = scalerI.transform(TestIn_ps)      maybe I didn' t use the scaler in a good way and I scaled only the two inputs and not the output.. But is there an explicit way to have a specific range for the output of the regression?

Comment: Can you post some parts of the data (as mentioned by @pyan) or a at least a code snippet which exposes the unwanted behaviour? Otherwise it'll be difficult to diagnose the problem...